# for loop apeend to vector

Tags: python, keras, model

I have a y_test.shape = (2005, 1) I build a model and did a prediction as follow prediction=model1.predict(np.array(test_x))

I got prediction shape (2005, 7)

I wanted to get the model accuracy but due to diffrent shapes I can't perform perform accuracy calculation. The way model predict worked is each class was in a column and if the pictures belongs to the class it will have 1. Is there a way to make it vector with each row corresponding to the class number.

Also is there another way to get the accuracy of the prediction if I have the labeled test? and I want to compare it with the prediction?

Answer (score 0):

Assume `prediction` is the predicted probability of `test_x` in each and every class, yo u may use `prediction.argmax(axis=1)` to get a size-2005 vector containing the index of the predicted class (from 0 to 6).  The prediction loss can also be computed

```
pred_class = prediction.argmax(axis=1)
l2loss = ((pred_class - y_test[:, 0]) ** 2).mean()
```

`y_test[:, 0]` merely change a matrix `(2005, 1)` to a vector of size 2005.  Or you may do the 0/1 loss as

```
binary_loss = (pred_class != y_test[:, 0]).mean()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and how do I get the accuracy of the model?